# Is there any way to speed up the drawing process in the following Java program?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, awt, polygon

This program draws a square on screen using fillPolygon() method.On executing the code, the drawing part is very slow. How can i improve this? Or is it that GUI development using Java AWT is worst?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class BluePolygon extends Frame {
int x, x1, y, y1;
    public BluePolygon() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                x1 = me.getX();
                y1 = me.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(Color.blue.getRed(),Color.blue.getGreen(),Color.blue.getBlue(),60));
        int xx[] = {x1,x,x,x1};
        int yy[] = {y,y,y1,y1};
        g.fillPolygon(xx, yy, 4);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BluePolygon winapp = new BluePolygon();
        winapp.setTitle("Blue Polygon");
        winapp.setSize(1200, 720);
        winapp.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is it that GUI development using Java AWT is worst?

I'd say so.

You can compare it with a Swing environment, which in my PC at least, works better.

```
public class BluePolygon extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int x, x1, y, y1;

    public BluePolygon() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                x1 = me.getX();
                y1 = me.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(Color.blue.getRed(), Color.blue.getGreen(), Color.blue.getBlue(), 60));
        int xx[] = { x1, x, x, x1 };
        int yy[] = { y, y, y1, y1 };
        g.fillPolygon(xx, yy, 4);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            BluePolygon winapp = new BluePolygon();
            winapp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(winapp);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```